# Does defense bonus from class increase as you level up?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

In the Star Wars revised saga edition, classes gain a defense bonus. My question is do they increase as they level up, or do they constantly stay the same unless you multiclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Saga Edition they do not go up as you level. Nor do they stack if you multiclass, you get the highest for each defence.

Saga Edition Core rulebook, page 36:

> "Class bonuses do not stack; you only apply the best bonus from all your classes to each defence score. Continuing the previous example, if you were a scout 6/soldier 2 you would have a +2 class bonus to your Fortitude defence (this is the better bonus, granted by being a solider), and a +2 class bonus to your Reflex defence (also the better bonus, granted by being a scout). If you later added a level of noble, you would also gain a +2 class bonus to your Will defence."

Answer (score 1):

Saga Edition provides defense bonuses as a feat-like class ability, not as a level dependent feature. None of the SWSE corebook classes indicate any increases at higher levels.

This is different from the earlier d20 System Star Wars, which gave them as level dependent features.

Note: I'm only aware of 3 WOTC editions of Star Wars:

- Star Wars d20
- Star Wars d20 Revised
- Star Wars Saga Edition